# Is Robinson’s non standard analysis accepted by the mathematical community?

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

Up until now I had known that calculus had been initially formulated by Leibniz and Newton in terms of infinitesimals, but that approach led to inconsistencies, and so Cauchy and others reformulated calculus rigorously using the epsilon-delta method.

Recently I stumbled across “Elementary Calculus : An Infinitesimal Approach” by H. J. Keisler. In his preface Keisler says that the infinitesimal approach to calculus had been placed on rigorous footing in the 1960s by Abraham Robinson.

And here is my question : is it universally accepted now that Robinson’s calculus is rigorous/not logically inconsistent? In essence, what’s the common consensus in the math community regarding Robinson’s approach to infinitesimal calculus?

Comment: No inconsistencies; see [Nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) as well as [Criticism of nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_nonstandard_analysis)

Comment: Yes, it is universally accepted.

Comment: Robinson's reformulation of calculus is accepted as rigorous and not logically inconsistent. This is so universally accepted, that you probably won't be able to find even one professional mathematician who claims that *the usual Cauchy-Weierstrass-etc. formulation is consistent but Robinson's formulation isn't*.

Comment: I would re-formulate the title of your question into: "Is Robinson's non-standard analysis accepted by mathematical community ?"

Comment: @JeanMarie done.

Comment: The majority opinion is that, pedagogically, it's a lot of pain for very little gain. A minority will disagree, and happily teach Calculus via nonstandard analysis. But truth is not determined by majority rule.